# Can't get internet access on Mac OS X 10.6 virtual machine

Tags: macos, windows-8, osx-snow-leopard, vmware-workstation

I am currently trying to get internet access on my Mac OS X 10.6 virtual machine. I am running Windows 8 as the host OS and using VmWare Workstation 10. I have created the VM using an ISO image of Mac OS X 10.6 and have the whole operating system up and running well. However, whenever I try to connect to the internet I don't have a connection. I have tried using the "bridged" option for the Network adapter of the host OS (Windows 8) but I am having no luck. I have also tried the other options and none of them are working.The only option I am getting is the Telephone Modem which is no use. 
Can anyone help?
Help is very much appreciated :)
Thanks.

Comment: This is all running on a Apple computer otherwise we cannot really help you.

Comment: Which model of Mac are you running this on?

Comment: I'm running it on a Windows computer (HP laptop). I.e. I'm not using a Mac.

Comment: @user256075 - We are going to be unable to help with an hackintosh problem.  This could in so many words simply be an hackintosh problem even if its virtual.

Comment: Okay. Do you know where I could get help for a Hackintosh problem? Thanks anyway.